# Multiple values to single variable python

Tags: python, variables

I am tryin to create some really basic list (using Python) only for practice but I am struggling to find answer for how to add multiple values to a single variable. Program should read one or another depending upon a users input.

I wish to enter multiple values to a single variable so that I can use just that "variable" later on.

Answer (score 0):

## In summary

What you're looking for is a dictionary or list. Variables in Python can have a single value, and assigning 2 values will cause a syntax error. Dictionaries are referenced by key, so you can ask for user input, and if it matches with a key, return the value corresponding to that key. Arrays are not indexed by a value (the aforementioned key), but rather ordered numerically.

### How to apply a dictionary

##### Based on user input

```py
#initialize dictionary
num_dict = {"green":1, "blue":2, "grey":3}

color = input("what is your favorite color? ")
if color in num_dict.keys(): #returns a list of keys: ["green", "blue", "grey"]
    print("Your number is" + num_dict[color]) 

#the num_dict[color] syntax references the value specified by the key, 
#for example if the user had entered green, since "green":1, the output 
#would be "Your number is 1"

else:
    print("your color is not a key. you don't get a number")
```

### How to apply an array

##### Based on user input

```py
#initialize array
num_arr = [1337, 31337, 1, 15]

color = input("what is your favorite color? ")

index = len(num_arr) % len(color)
#the index here is specified by the length of the string, normalized into a
#usable index using modulus (gets the remainder of division) and the length of the array (since indexes must
#be less than the length-1 (because arrays are 0-indexed)

#brief explanation of array indexing
# [1337, 31337, 1, 15]
# arr[0] = 1337
# arr[1] = 31337
# arr[4] = *runtime error*

#worked example of the num_arr[index] code:
# num_arr = [1337, 31337, 1, 15]
# len(num_arr) = 4

# given:
# color = "red"
# len(color) = 3
# index = 4 % 3 = 1
# num_arr[index] = 31337

# given
# color = "grey"
# len(color) = 4
# index = 4 % 4 = 0, note that an index greater than 3, our highest possible array index, is impossible
# num_arr[index] = 1337

# given:
# color = "yellow"
# len(color) = 6
# index = 4 % 6 = 2
# num_arr[index] = 1

print("Your number is" + str(num_arr[index]))
```